# HTML is not giving desired output

Tags: html, css

Been struggling with an issue for two days, but don't seem to see what the problem might be.

I am trying to learn HTML and working on my own website. However, I am having trouble moving ahead, as I am not getting any output from my HTML code. I have inserted my code into HTML validator, including the CSS, but it didn't give any errors back. What am I doing wrong?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang= "no">
   <head>
        <title>Rick Mason</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
   </head>
```

```
     <header>
     <nav>
     <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Om meg</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Arbeidserfaring</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Prosjektliste</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sertifikater</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
      </header>

    <main>
        <p>This is just a test of some text </p>
     </main>

   </body>


   </html>


       body {
          height: 125vh;
          background-color: #EEE8AA;
          background-size: cover;
          font-family: sans-serif;
             }


       header{
          background-color: white;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          height: 100px;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
          border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
                }

       header *{
            display: inline;
                 }

        header li{
            margin: 10px;

                }

       header li a {
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
              }

   li a:hover {
         background:#4cb15e;
         border-radius: 25px;
         padding: 8px;
               }
```

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: @viktorF : Yes, this is all my code so far, both my HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Do you want your links to be next to each other or in a list, downwards?

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: @PythonMaster202 : I want my links to be placed nex to each other (horizontally) as they are now. However, right now they are aligned to the left. How can I center my links?

Comment: @RickMason Updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting some output - I tried pasting your code into a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e247ghn9/1/

It seems like you're missing an opening `<body>` tag, though. That might be why.

UPDATE:

It's because you're using `position: fixed` on the navigation bar, so your content gets hidden by it. You should probably use some top margin on the rest of the content, like this:

```css
main {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @Vikctor F : I am sorry, the opening tag <body> is present in my code. Before I posted my question I was struggling to put code into my post and therefore some code must have been deleted while I was making some adjustments, like the opening body tag. I just checked my actual code, and the opening tag <body> is present in my actual code on line 9. 

You are correct, I am seeing the same output in my web browser as you are seeing in jsfiddle. However, I am not able to move forward with my HTML code. 

In lines 23-25 I am adding more text to the main body , but that is not showing up in outp

Comment: If line 23-25 are the lines between `</body>` and `</html>` (as in my fiddle), then it makes sense. You can't add markup outside of the `body` element

Comment: @RickMason Ah, now I see :). It's because you're using `position: fixed` on the navigation bar, so your content gets hidden by the navbar

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks, that solved my problem. Adding margin-top of 100px solved the problem. No I see the text that I was trying to output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine. You just need to separate html and css code into separate file. Following is the working demo.

```css
body {
  height: 125vh;
  background-color: #EEE8AA;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


header {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}

header * {
  display: inline;
}

header li {
  margin: 10px;

}

header li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #4cb15e;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no">

<head>
  <title>Rick Mason</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>


  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Om meg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Arbeidserfaring</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prosjektliste</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sertifikater</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>This is just a test of some text </p>
  </main>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the script, and if it doesn't work now, I don't know what will.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no">

<head>
  <title>Rick Mason</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Om meg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Arbeidserfaring</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prosjektliste</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sertifikater</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>This is just a test of some text </p>
  </main>

</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 125vh;
  background-color: #EEE8AA;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}

header {
  display: inline;
}

header li {
  margin: 10px;

}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #4cb15e;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a page wrapper to give the page a min-height of 100%, then it will show the content correct on all devices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rick Mason</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Om meg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Arbeidserfaring</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prosjektliste</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sertifikater</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>This is just a test of some text </p>
  </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Because the header menu is fixed, you have to give the main a padding-top of minimal the height of the menu, for example 120px. I added some minimal css to give you a starting point.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body, body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #eee8aa;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
#page {
  min-height: 100%;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
header ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
header li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li a:hover, li a:active {
  background: #4cb15e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
main {
  /* header height + some extra whitespace */
  padding-top: 120px; 
}
```